# string manupilation based on the pattern of two columns, any convenient way?

Tags: python, pandas

```
d = {'country': ['US', 'US', 'United Kingdom', 'United Kingdom'],
    'province/state': ['New York', np.nan, 'Gibraltar', np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I guess there are three steps:

1. Step 1: fill the NA of the province with the related country

   `df['province/state'].fillna(df['country'], inplace=True]`
2. Step 2: create a new col by concatenating the country and province with '-':

   `df['new_geo'] = df['country'] + '-' + df['province/state']`
3. Step 3: remove the country if it is repeated:
   for example, remove United Kingdom-United Kingdom. Only keep those which are not overlapped, such as United Kingdom-Gibraltar. But I am not sure what regex should be used.

Is there any convenient way to do this?

Comment: it helps if u post what ur final output should look like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['new_geo'] = np.where(df['province/state'].notna(), df['country'] + '-' + df['province/state'], df['country'])
df['province/state']=df['province/state'].fillna(df['country'])
```

Outputs:

```py
          country  province/state                   new_geo
0              US        New York               US-New York
1              US              US                        US
2  United Kingdom       Gibraltar  United Kingdom-Gibraltar
3  United Kingdom  United Kingdom            United Kingdom
```

Answer (score 1):

combine strings usings [pandas str cat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html), then fill the empty cells sideways using [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) with axis=1.

```
res = (df
       .assign(new_geo = lambda x: x.country.str.cat(x['province/state'],sep='-'))
       .ffill(axis=1)
      )

res

  country         province/state    new_geo
0   US              New York        US-New York
1   US                US            US
2   United Kingdom  Gibraltar       United Kingdom-Gibraltar
3   United Kingdom  United Kingdom  United Kingdom
```